# Please help me identify this tree/fruit. Is it edible?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees, fruit

When free, could the experts here please help me identify this tree.

**Location:** Delhi, India

**Height:** 20-30 feet

**Date:** October

Is the hanging green colored fruit edible?

Thank you for all the kindness in Biology SE.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like *Catalpa bignonioides*, aka the **Indian bean tree** and is commonly used as a garden or street tree.[¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalpa_bignonioides) The plant is  native to the southeastern United States but was introduced in northern India later.[²](https://powo.science.kew.org/taxon/urn:lsid:ipni.org:names:30194969-2)

#### Regarding edibility:

**No**,  I would not recommend eating any part of it as multiple websites list it to have no edible uses, and the roots are [highly poisonous](https://pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Catalpa%20bignonioides)[³](https://pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Catalpa%20bignonioides) [⁴](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/catalpa-edible-90090.html)

[image]
[image]

References:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalpa_bignonioides
2. https://powo.science.kew.org/taxon/urn:lsid:ipni.org:names:30194969-2
3. https://pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Catalpa+bignonioides
4. https://homeguides.sfgate.com/catalpa-edible-90090.html